# Transformations on a discrete function. Make it wider and flatter.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, transformation

Say I have a discrete function encoded in two arrays of the same size. Array $X$ and array $Y$, where each $Y[i]$ corresponds to each $X[i]$.

There are two types of modifications I need to be able to perform to my $Y[i]$ values.

1) I need to modify them as to make the function wider/narrower.

2) I need to make it flatter/sharper.

Can anyone point me towards the right direction, how can I transform a function in these ways.

Answer (score 0):

It works similar to continuous time functions:

1) It depends on how is your function encoded. if its something like $X = sin(t)$, its enough to multiply the $t$ for a constant. $X = sin(t*A)$ the narrower or wider of the function is controlled with the constant $A$.

2) To make it flatter or sharper, the function has to be element wise multiplied for a constant, means that each element of the array has to be multiplied for the exact same constant, lets say $A$. If $A>1$ then it becomes sharper, if $A<1$ becomes flatter, and if $A = 1$ it remains the same.

Comment: In 1), what if I don't know the functional form? I only have discrete points $(X[I], Y[i])$

Comment: Do you mean make it wider or narrower by the distance between the points? or by the function itself?

Comment: if you mean the function itself without knowing the functional form, then the easiest way is to insert points between the ones that you know. You can find the values of the inserted points with a regression.
If you mean the distance between points it would depend on the software that you are using.